# Google Sheets Vertical Lookup Query

Tags: google-sheets

I am setting up a spreadsheet for my D&D game, the campaign has a focus on committing sinful or virtuous acts and scoring sin or virtue points that interact with the game world. Anyway, I have a table set up so the rows are for tracking sin and virtue points gained and the columns are for tracking the characters. I would like to have a section at the bottom that returns the sin or virtue the player has the most points in, so I can at a glance know if they are particularly sinful or virtuous. I'm trying to use the VLOOKUP function with the LARGE function serving as the search key, but it is returning an error. [Screenshot of my spreadsheet and formula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYl9f.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Answer (score 0):

LARGE is finding the right value but VLOOKUP is not finding that value in ColumnA (and without the 4th parameter TRUE is assumed, which can give highly unexpected results). Anyway, VLOOKUP cannot 'look to the left', so INDEX/MATCH is better:

```
=index(A:A,match(large(B2:B15,1),B:B,0))
```

Note that this only finds the first (from the top) instance of any maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

Try SORTN:

```
=SORTN(A2:A15,1,,B2:B15,0)
```